# Load multiple bitmaps in Android Studio one at time with threads

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap, java-threads

I'm currently working on a project which takes pictures from camera and saves the photoPath in a Database, this is working fine and actually I'm handling the memory correctly generating thumbnails when I load all images.

The thing I want is that I'm trying to dedicate threads to go loading images one per one in the layout, because for example, if I have 50, with normal load it shows the layout until all 50 are loaded, meanwhile it doesn't show anything.

I've already tried to implement this threads to load one, and then another one, but it's the same, until it loads all, it shows all, here my code:

```
    String query = "Select id_reg_mem, information from Memory_REG where type = 'PHOTO' and id_memory =" + id_memory;
        final Cursor resultado = memoryDB.rawQuery(query, null);

if(resultado.moveToFirst())
            noPhotos = resultado.getCount();

for(int i=0; i<noPhotos; i++)
        {
            new Thread()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            updateNewPhoto(resultado.getString(1)); // I send the path from the DB to a method I made to add a tablerow with the image (inside an imageview)
                        }
                    });
                }
            }.start();

            if(i + 1 == noPhotos)
                break;
            resultado.moveToNext();
        }
```

Here this method, where I'm loading a single image to an ImageView inside a TableRow. This method is actually working to load all images from DB.

```
protected void updateNewPhoto(String path)
    {
        ImageView iv;
        if(rows == null) {
            rows = new ArrayList<TableRow>();
            rows.add(new TableRow(TL.getContext()));
            iv = new ImageView(TL.getContext());
            iv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(250,250));
            iv.setTag(DB_Utils.maxIDRegMem(memoryDB) - 1);
            iv.setImageBitmap(getBitmapThumbnail(path));
            rows.get(0).addView(iv);
            TL.addView(rows.get(0));
            count = 2;
        }

        else
        {
            iv = new ImageView(TL.getContext());
            iv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(250,250));
            iv.setTag(DB_Utils.maxIDRegMem(memoryDB) - 1);
            iv.setImageBitmap(getBitmapThumbnail(path));
            if(count == 2)
            {
                rows.get(rows.size() - 1).addView(iv);
                count = 1;
            }

            else
            {
                rows.add(new TableRow(TL.getContext()));
                rows.get(rows.size() - 1).addView(iv);
                TL.addView(rows.get(rows.size() - 1));
                count = 2;
            }
        }
```

Unfortunately for me, all images aren't shown until all of them are loaded (kind of 3 seconds it takes). I'm thinking in no limit of images, that's why I want a way where images be loaded one per one, not all together.

Any ideas you have? I appreciate your help.
Thanks.

Comment: You should use a 3rd party library like Glide or Picasso

Comment: You can use AsyncTask. In doInBackground() function loop over the URL list to get the image/bitmap. Then publish it using publishProgress(). Calling publishProgress() will pass the control on onProgressUpdate(). In this (onProgressUpdate)  update the UI.